# Get Intersection points between line and quadrilateral in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to find the intersection points between line and quadrilateral in c#.In the below image the points are blue circles. I searched but not found any solution in google.

I am using this in unity3d and quadrilateral is a mesh.So from mesh I can get the bounds using `mesh.bounds` and in my case the line is something as `z=c`.

Thanks

[image: Example Image]

Comment: have you 2 points of the line?

Comment: Yeah I have 2 points on the line

Comment: You can use maths, make 1 line with 2 points of the bounds and got 2 lines intersection: http://www.ambrsoft.com/MathCalc/Line/TwoLinesIntersection/TwoLinesIntersection.htm

Comment: You have to take into account concave ones too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bound points of your plane to make 2 lines on each side you like to know the intersection and check if intersect with your other line.

There you have an script to make an interseccion with 2 lines.
p1-p2 is the first line points, p3-p4 is the second line points:

```
static public Vector2 GetIntersection (Vector2 p1 , Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3, Vector2 p4)
    {   
    //Determinamos m1 como perpendicular de la recta p1-p2 pasando por p1

        float m1 = pendiente (p1, p2);
        float m2 = pendiente (p3,p4);
        float b1 = ordenada (p1, m1);
        float b2 = ordenada (p3, m2);
        Vector2 interseccion = new Vector2(0f , 0f);    

        if (m1 == m2)
        {

            interseccion = new Vector2(p2.x , p2.y);


        }
        else
        {
            float x = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2);
            float y = (m1 * x) + b1;

            interseccion = new Vector2(x , y);
        }

        return interseccion;
    }

static public float pendiente (Vector2 p1 , Vector2 p2)
    {

    float m = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
    return m;

    }

    static public float ordenada (Vector2 p1, float m)
    {
    float b = p1.y - (m * p1.x);
    return b;       
    }
```